# I want to set a unique permissions folder inside a drop off library

Tags: permissions, drop-off-library

Our group will use the drop off library.  My concern is if a document is left in the drop off library waiting on meta data to be complete, I do not want everyone to have access to that document.  How do I get around this.  My thought was creating a folder inside the drop off library with unique permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Out of the Box Content Approval.

Step 1: Enable content approval and specify draft item security for the library

Step 2: Enable major and minor versioning for the library

Step 3: Set up a workflow to manage content approval for a library

[More On how to do these activities](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/use-a-workflow-to-manage-content-approval-for-a-library-HA010172010.aspx)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/30/sharepoint-2010-content-organizer-part-3-the-rules-engine.aspx

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer about how the achieve this? Right now it is very dependent on the links, that might break

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 views that each turn on or off a filter: the default view activates a filter that hides all documents waiting on meta-data to be complete and the 2nd view (perhaps called "admin view"?) displays all documents.

Here are the specific steps (using SP2010, which is what I use).

1. In your drop off library, create a new column called "Metadata_Complete". Its type can be single line of text.
2. For the default view: Select "Modify this view". Scroll down to the FILTER section. Select "Show items only when the following is true". Select the "Metadata_Complete" column IS NOT EQUAL TO. Leave the value blank (because, by default, you want the drop off library to NOT display any documents that are waiting for meta-data to be complete). Click OK to save.
3. For the 2nd/admin view, or the view you probably have now: No FILTER value is set (because you want the view to display everything).
4. To test: Upload a document to your drop off library. By default, the document should NOT display. Using your 2nd/admin view, fill in the meta-data. In the Metadata_Complete column, type in YES (etc) and save. Since the filter on the default view only filters out blank values in the Metadata_Complete column, you should now see the document.